# Return CFC Query Data from AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I am making an AJAX call to a CFC to return one record from my database. The record is always returned as a string.  I then update an input field with that value.

The problem is that my field is being populated with the following:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>0</string></data</wddxPacket>
```

Instead, I only want the value of the string. In this example: `0`

**AJAX Call:**

```
<script>
function populateSalesTax(){
    // Populate the start and stop odometer text boxes
    // when the selectlist ajax completes successfully

        $.ajax({
            url:'cfcs/taxdata.cfc?method=getSalesTax',
            data: { company_name: $("##company_name>option:selected").attr("Value") },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Sales Tax Fubction Ran Successfully');
                $("##taxRate").val( response );

                },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log('Error' + response)}
          });
    }
</script>
```

**CFC Function:**

```
<cffunction name="getSalesTax" access="remote" returnType="string">
   <cfargument name="company_name" type="any" required="true">

   <!--- localize function variables --->
   <cfset var taxDetail = "">
   <cfoutput>
   <cfquery name="taxDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
       SELECT tax_rate
       FROM   customer_table
       <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
       WHERE company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.company_name#"
                                cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
   </cfquery>
   </cfoutput>

   <cfreturn taxDetail.tax_rate>
</cffunction>
```

**Input Field:**

```
<cfinput name="taxRate" id="taxRate" type="text" size="2" readonly="yes">
```

Comment: In your AJAX call, try `cfcs/taxdata.cfc?method=getSalesTax&ReturnFormat=json`

Comment: The easy way is to not use ajax at all.  Run the function in your .cfm file and use the value attribute of your cfinput tag.  Not related to your question, but you don't need a cfoutput tag in your function.  cfquery has one built in.

Comment: Why would you suggest the easiest way is to not use AJAX?

Comment: There is nothing in the question that suggests that the value he wants changes with user activity.  That being the case, ajax appears to be an unnecessary complication.

Comment: And if said functionality exists, your suggestion to not use AJAX would cause it to stop working.

Answer (score 1):

I have a lot of code here because I do things a lot different than most, but it's been an evolution.
Here's how I create a typical table:

```
if exists (select * from sysobjects where id = object_id(N'myTable') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE myTable
GO
CREATE TABLE myTable(
myTableID Int Identity(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
,myTableName varchar(128) default ''
,myTableDesc varchar(max) default ''
,myTableSort Int default 0
)
GO
INSERT INTO myTable(myTableName,myTableSort) VALUES('One',1)
INSERT INTO myTable(myTableName,myTableSort) VALUES('Two',2)
INSERT INTO myTable(myTableName,myTableSort) VALUES('Three',3)
```

I use stored procedures. Here's the SQL code:

```
create schema myTable authorization dbo
-- It might seem odd to create a schema called with the name of the table, but that's how I organize the stored procedures by table name.
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'myTable.[get]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROC myTable.[get]
GO
CREATE PROC myTable.[get]
(@UsrID Int
,@RemoteAddr Varchar(15)
,@myTableID Int
) AS
SELECT myTableID,myTableName,myTableDesc,myTableSort
FROM myTable
WHERE myTableID = @myTableID
GO
exec myTable.[get] 0,'',1001
```

@UsrID is the first parameter in every stored procedure. It's who wants to know.

@RemoteAddr is the second parameter in every stored procedure. It's the IP address of the user.
Now, I know it's not foolproof, but the think here is the security is such that
1) @UsrID is something they know (they had to know the password to get logged in as the user).

2) @RemoteAddr is something they own (although IP addresses can be spoofed).

@myTableID is the primary key to @myTable. I always name the primary key the table name followed by ID.

Here's a typical .cfm page:

```
<cfscript>

</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
<cfinclude template="/Inc/html.cfm">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css">
<cfinclude template="/Inc/body.cfm">
<ul>
    <li><a class="myClass" data-mytableid="1000" href="JavaScript:;">Click One!</a></li>
    <li><a class="myClass" data-mytableid="1001" href="JavaScript:;">Click Two!</a></li>
    <li><a class="myClass" data-mytableid="1002" href="JavaScript:;">Click Three!</a></li>
</ul>
<cfinclude template="/Inc/foot.cfm">
<script src="Index.js"></script>
<cfinclude template="/Inc/End.cfm">
</cfoutput>
```

A script that I include in all my pages:

```
window.dom = {}
dom.msg = $('#msg')
dom.main = $('main')
dom.fail = function(xhr, status, response) {
    dom.msg.text(status + ': ' + response).addClass('label-warning')
    dom.main.html(xhr.responseText)
    debugger
}
```

And the script for the page itself:

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.myClass',clicked)

    function clicked() {
        var local = {}
        local.url = 'myTable.cfc'
        local.type = 'POST' // or GET
        local.dataType = 'json'
        local.data = {}
        local.data.method = 'get';
        local.data.myTableID = $(this).data('mytableid')
        local.context = this;
        result = $.ajax(local)
        result.fail(dom.fail)
        result.done(done)
    }
    function done(response, status, xhr) {
//      console.log(response.COLUMNS)
//      console.log(response.DATA)
//      console.log(response.DATA[0])
//      console.log(response.DATA[0][0]) // myTableID
//      console.log(response.DATA[0][1]) // myTableName
//      console.log(response.DATA[0][2]) // myTableDesc
//      console.log(response.DATA[0][3]) // myTableSort
//      console.log(status)
//      console.log(xhr)
    }
})()
```

Finally, myTable.cfc:

```
component {

remote function get(myTableID) returnformat='json' {
    storedproc dataSource=session.dataSource
        procedure='myTable.[get]' {
        procparam cfSqlType='cf_sql_integer' value=session.Usr.UsrID;
        procparam cfSqlType='cf_sql_varchar' value=session.RemoteAddr;
        procparam cfSqlType='cf_sql_integer' value=arguments.myTableID;
        procresult resultset=1 name='result';
    }
    return result
}
}
```

And I should paste an abbreviated Application.cfc:

```
component {
this.Name = 'myAJAX'
this.dataSource = 'LR2015Summer1'
this.SessionManagement = true

function onSessionStart() {
    session.dataSource = this.dataSource
    session.RemoteAddr = getPageContext().getRequest().getRemoteAddr()
    session.Usr = {}
    session.Usr.UsrID = 0
}

function onRequestStart(LogCFCName) {
    setting showDebugOutput=false;
    if (isDefined('url.onSessionStart')) {
        onSessionStart()
    }
    request.msg = ''
    request.mod = 'label-info'

    request.title='How I AJAX and return a query'
    request.home = '/HowIWrite/AJAX/cfc'
    request.css       = url.css       ?: true
    request.js        = url.js        ?: true
    request.bootstrap = url.bootstrap ?: true
    request.bootstrap_theme = 'bootstrap-theme'
    request.tryCatch  = url.tryCatch  ?: false
    request.navbar    = url.navbar    ?: true
    request.container = url.container ?: true
    request.GoogleMaterialdesign = url.GoogleMaterialdesign ?: true
    request.jQueryUI  = url.jQueryUI  ?: false
    request.jQueryUI_theme = 'ui-lightness' // black-tie,blitzer,cupertino,dark-hive,dot-luv,eggplant,excite-bike,flick,hot-sneaks,humanity,le-frog,mint-choc,overcast,pepper-grinder,redmond,smoothness,south-street,start,sunny,swanky-purse,trontastic,ui-darkness,ui-lightness,vader

    request.cgiName = getPageContext().getRequest().getServletPath()
    request.cgiName = Left(request.cgiName,Len(request.cgiName)-4)
    request.cgiName = ListLast(request.cgiName,'/')
    request.cssName = request.cgiName & '.css'
    request.jsName  = request.cgiName & '.js'
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can modify your CFC as such:**

```
<cfset response = { taxRate = taxDetail.tax_rate } />
<cfreturn serializeJSON(response)>
```

(ajax success method should have `response.TAXRATE`)

**or your ajax call url as such:**

`cfcs/taxdata.cfc?method=getSalesTax&ReturnFormat=json`

***But***

Judging from you relative path in the ajax request `url:'cfcs/taxdata.cfc?method=getSalesTax'` I can safely assume that you're trying to do an ajax request on the same origin (same site) and you don't actually *need* a `remote` method, but a `public` or `package` method.

You should be aware of the security headaches that come with declaring a method `remote`. Without a proper security layer or `role` defined you have opened the method for anybody to use, including malicious users.

**So** what you should have is:

- another abstraction layer in front of your CFC - at minimum just a cfm that instantiates the object and calls `getSalesTax`, but ideally a framework
- an access of `public` or `package` instead of `remote`
- an appropriate Content Type declared on the abstraction layer that returns the tax rate response object (e.g. `<cfcontent type="application/json" reset="true" />`)

Comment: I've not done many ajax calls, and none recently, but I have vague memories of issues unless the method is remote.

Comment: an ajax request is just like any other request except it is *asynchronous*, or out of turn. In modern browsers, an ajax request is prevented from running a call to a script on a different domain(origin) than the current domain, unless provided differently in the allow-origin-access header(look up CORS). This is implemented for security reasons concerning cross site scripting, compromised web apps, etc.  *In this case* I'm not saying it is an issue but rather I am suggesting that he closes the potential security hole in his app, and that is the remote method

Comment: I have started using a layer in between where the data comes from and where the data is used. Call it AppApi or something similar. AppApi has a class (maybe AppObj) instantiated, so AppApi has remote methods to call public methods on AppObj. The main benefit I see in doing things this way is the AppObj object is persistent in AppApi, but I think the methods in AppApi that a page calls need to be remote instead of public or package. Am I confused about what you are saying?

Comment: Who is consuming this api? Is it just your webapp or is it for 3rd party apps? Does your api require any form of authentication? The reason I'm asking this is to determine whether or not you actually *need* remote methods. Access **remote** creates a webservice that remote apps or 3rd party apps can consume.

Comment: If that's not the case then you don't need it a remote method, but here is a simplistic example of what you need: `myapp.com/index.cfm?action=getTax`. `Index.cfm` here has a decision block `if(action==getTax)` and if so it instantiates AppApi.AppObject and calls `myTax = AppObject.getSalesTax()`. Then to return json you can just add `<cfcontent type="application/json" reset="true" /><cfoutput>#serializeJSON(myTax)#</cfoutput>`. Here the getSalesTax method *does not* need to be remote, but public. This is a crude MVC approach. I would suggest looking into coldfusion mvc frameworks like  FW1.